# client.commands.get('kickembed').execute //cannot read property 'execute' is undefined//

Tags: discord.js, bots

I can actually run the bot, it will let mi interact with the other 3 commands, but when trying to do the "kickembed" it will fail and give me the error "client.commands.get('kickembed').execute(message,args,Discord)"
^
Cannot read property of 'execute' of undefined

tbh, i tried everithing, my little brain cant work this out, tysm for your time!

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = ('^');

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Cataclysm is online, beep bop')
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


            if(command === 'ping'){
            message.channel.send('pong!');
            } else if (command === 'welcome'){
            client.commands.get('welcome').execute(message, args);
            } else if (command === 'ban'){
            client.commands.get('Ban').execute(message, args);
            } else if (command === 'kick'){
            client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
            } else if (command === 'kickembed'){
            client.commands.get('kickembed').execute(message, args, Discord);
            }


}); ~~~


and this is "kickembed"(where i have the problem i think)

~~~    const name = 'kick';
    const description = "This command kicks a member!";
    function execute(message, args, Discord) {


        const banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

        .setColor('#ff3838')
        .setTitle('A user has been kicked')
        .setDescription('player (fix this plis) has been kicked by etc');

    message.channel.send(banembed);~~~
```

Comment: The title is misleading: it is not execute that is undefined, but `client.commands.get('kickembed')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `kickembed` files have wrong name it is `kick`

So it should be like:

```js
    const name = 'kickembed';
    const description = "This command kicks a member!";
    function execute(message, args, Discord) {


        const banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

        .setColor('#ff3838')
        .setTitle('A user has been kicked')
        .setDescription('player (fix this plis) has been kicked by etc');

    message.channel.send(banembed);
```

Comment: Hey there! Ty for the response... but this wont work... same error. Do you have any other idea on how to fix this? Thanks again!

Comment: I should want to get more details from you feel free to contact me at HellCatVN#1235

Comment: Sure, just sent you fr, (Minilink#8425)